# ASP.NET Response.Cookie client or server?

Tags: asp.net, cookies

When calling `Response.Cookie.Add(new HttpCookie("MyCookie", "objValue"));` where does the cookie saved? on Client Machine or Server Machine?

EDIT:
if saved in Client Machine, how can I read it from javascript then? I tried this kind of script.

```
function getCookie(c_name) {
    var i, x, y, ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i++) {
        x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
        y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
        x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
        if (x == c_name) {
            return unescape(y);
        }
     }
}
```

I cannot get the cookie that I saved from code behind.  When I look into the `document.cookie` object, it is just an empty string.

Scenario:

1. On Page_Init() on code behind. I create a cookie using `Response.Cookie.Add(new HttpCookie("MyCookie", "cookieValue"));`.
2. On Client side, I'm trying to read the cookie saved from code behind on page load using the snippet above, but it returns `undefined`

Comment: Why this complicated? Just put a hidden field (eg `asp:HiddenField`) in the page, fill its contents and read it with javascript.

Comment: @tiagoinu: I put that kind of scenario as an example.  I just want to know how to read the saved Cookies created from code behind in javascript.  Since all cookies are saved in Client machine.

Comment: sorry my bad... I can get the cookie from javascript.. I remove the cookie after I read it from code behind.. thanks anyways..

Comment: No problem. Please select an answer below or add your own. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Wikipedia explains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie), cookies string values that are stored on the client.
They are sent to server with each HTTP request as `Cookie:` headers.

You can store arbitrary objects in the server using [session state](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx).

Comment: thanks, but I was trying to read the cookie I saved using javascript, I just can't read it. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Client machine. I'm sure google could give you a good explanation, But I use it everyday, and experience is my source.

Comment: @Rob Note that the second parameter to the HttpCookie constructor is a string, not any object. You cannot save arbitrary objects in a cookie. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookie.aspx

Comment: @tiagoinu: You are correct. I was addressing the root of this question, not his syntax, or possible error/exceptions of his code

Comment: Yes, I mentioned it in a comment to your answer because that info did not merit an answer of its own.

Comment: @tiagoinu: I've edited my answer, I wasn't saving arbitrary object in a cookie, its just string.  and please review my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are always saved at Client Machine.